# which search engine for GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, search-engine, spring-roo

I would like to use SPRING ROO and the GAE...but Solr can not run on the GAE. So which alternative to Solr can I use to have a search engine for my website ?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [GAELucene](http://code.google.com/p/gaelucene/), which is a [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) based full-text search component for App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a stable solution. I would choose to run SOLR as an external web service (e.g on Amazon ec2 or why not on Amazon Beanstalk ) or wait for the GAE full text search(it should soon ). The other "solutions" are just workarounds and may be also quite expensive (based on the new pricing schema) so I would advice to use them only if your app is not business-critical.